# Rails opening gnuplot window only on local machine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, gnuplot

I'm using a ruby on rails 3 application to draw a plot via the gnuplot gem.

The problem is, that the gnuplot window opens on the machine on which the server is running, and the client browser gets stuck because you cant close the gnuplot window.

Is there any way to forward the output to the client? And yes, I already thought about writing the gnuplot output to file and embedding the image. But then I loose the gnuplot functionality like zoom and so on.

Comment: You can try the `canvas` terminal for interactive plots in the browser: http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_canvas_4.6/

Comment: yes, thank you, that is pretty much what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot forward a general interactive window to the client browser. But you can use the `canvas` terminal to produce interactive plots with zooming capabilities, see http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_canvas_4.6/ (I can't include any interactive example on this site).

Comment: yes that works rather nicely, but I cant seem to integrate it into my rails project. I can get the output to work standalone, but when I render it in rails it will only show basic HTML (like table) elements, no graphics.

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you with that. You must make sure, that all the required javascript scripts are loaded and you must call the correct javascript function when the page is loaded (see the source of the generated html file in standalone mode, or the documentation `help terminal canvas` for a minimal html script to include the plot).